# How to use a Must-Use plugin to hide a regular one and to hide itself?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mu-plugins

When solving this issue ( [Change admin language based on user (in single-site)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53326/12615) ), I did a function so that the plugin would auto-hide from all users except one (me:).

The flaw is that it only auto-hides when *active*.

At first, it was a mu-plugin, but I had to enable/disable it manually. It really doesn't need to run all the time, as it may slow the site (?) or even contain some sensitive manipulation of the site's language (another question mark).

But mainly the motivation is that I don't want the client activating/deactivating/deleting this plugin (is for my own use), and don't want it cluttering her own plugins list.

So, decided to split the functions in two plugins:

- One is a Must-Use used to hide the regular one.
- The other will be activated/deactivated upon necessity and is the one from the above linked issue.

But now I run into another question: **how to hide one plugin from the Must-Use listing**?

Comment: Everytime I stumble upon this Q/A I want to +1 it another time.

Comment: @kaiser, yep, I like this trick a lot too, *`No MustUse nor DontDisable here, folks, please, move along, move along...`* :) You know you can +100, right? :P

Comment: Yep. And I will. Just right after I passed Mike and can afford 100 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there's no way to remove *one* plugin from the Must-Use list...

But then, found a filter that does even better:
`show_advanced_plugins` will completely hide the sight of the Must-Use plugins.

After all, if you're trying to hide something of this nature, then hide it all...

It's inside the class `WP_Plugins_List_Table` and takes two arguments: a boolean and the plugin type (`mustuse` and `dropins`).

Check [this article](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/) for a reference of MU and **specially** Drop-ins. But, for the sake of the wiki, I'll post the DI table at the end of this answer.

---

**Update:**
 - `mu-plugin` updated to multiple users and multiple *hide* plugins <sup>was string now it's array</sup>

---

### The Drop-in plugin

For testing this procedure we need one of those. Create a file named ***`db.php`*** at the **root** of your wp-content folder and copy this:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Just for testing Drop-ins
    Version: 0.1
    Author: WPSE-53866
    Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
*/
```

---

### The Must-use plugin

Then, this one inside the `mu-plugins` folder, and set the parameters of the class.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Hide Must-Use and Drop-ins from the Plugins listing
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53866
Description: Used to hide the Must-Use and Drop-ins plugins from all users except one. Also can hide a selected plugin from the regular list, be it active or not.
Version: 1.1
Author: brasofilo
AuthorURI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/
*/

/**
 * Parameters of the class - sorry for the non-standard documentation
 *
 * @super_admin     : array   (required)    : the users which are able to see everything
 * @can_see_mustuse : boolean (required)    : can other users see the Must-Use list?
 * @can_see_dropins : boolean (required)    : can other users see the Drop-ins list?
 * @hide_this_one   : array   (optional)    : plugins to hide in the regular listing
 *
 * Reference article for Must-Use and Drop-ins
 * http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/
 */

add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_53866_fire_plugin');

function wpse_53866_fire_plugin() 
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'plugins.php' != $pagenow) 
        return;

    $wpse53866_HideAdvancedPlugins_instance = new Wpse53866_HideAdvancedPlugins(
        array(
            'super_admin'       => array('Rodolfo','roda'),
            'can_see_mustuse'   => false,
            'can_see_dropins'   => true,
            'hide_this_ones'    => array( 'set-user-locale.php', 'akismet/akismet.php' )
        )
    );
}

class Wpse53866_HideAdvancedPlugins
{
    public function __construct($data)
    {       
        $this->user     = $data['super_admin'];
        $this->mustuse  = $data['can_see_mustuse'];
        $this->dropins  = $data['can_see_dropins'];
        $this->hide     = isset( $data['hide_this_ones'] ) ? $data['hide_this_ones'] : false;

        if($this->hide)
            add_filter( 'all_plugins', array(&$this, 'on_list_plugins' ) );

        add_filter( 'show_advanced_plugins', array(&$this, 'on_list_advanced' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    public function on_list_plugins($plugins)
    {
            global $current_user;

            if( ! in_array( $current_user->user_login, $this->user ) )
            {
                foreach( $this->hide as $plug )
                    unset( $plugins[$plug] );               
            }

           return $plugins;
    }

    public function on_list_advanced($show, $type)
    {
            global $current_user;

            if( ! in_array( $current_user->user_login, $this->user ) ) 
            {
                if( 'mustuse' == $type ) 
                    return $this->mustuse;

                if( 'dropins' == $type ) 
                    return $this->dropins;
            }

           return true;
    }
}
```

---

### Reference

by [hakre on wordpress](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/)

[image: list of drop-ins plugins]

Comment: Do not create an instance on every page load, wait until the hook fires you want to catch. Your plugin will now run even on AJAX requests. For language specific hacks use the `$langname.php` in `/languages/`.

Comment: @toscho , oh, my, thanks maestro, looks like I did a brute force attack, will amend ASAP :)

Comment: Plugin initialization corrected for only firing in the right place. I simply copy-pasted another concept without attention to the consequences. Thanks toscho for the analytic eye. But the language hack is really very specific for enabling english as admin language for only *one* user on a german site, will revise its code as well JIC.

Comment: Put a `de_DE.php` into the language directory. It will be used like a plugin.

Comment: @toscho - in this example, I'm not dealing with languages and am using `akismet/akismet.php` as the sample plugin to hide from the main list. In my text I'm referring to [another plugin for swapping languages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53678/12615) according to the `user_login`. It uses `add_filter('locale', func);` and manipulates the output. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Another use: in a **Multisite** environment, suppose that we have a *site specific* plugin. Not a Must Use, but a regular plugin, tailor made for just one site.

It lives on `example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php`.

We'll make a Must Use plugin, `/mu-plugins/hide-plugins.php` like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: One site only
 * Description: Hide site specific plugin from other sites
 **/

add_action('plugins_loaded', function () 
{
    # Set filter to all sites, except ID 15
    $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
    if( $blog_id == 15 )
        return;

    # Alternative for subdomain installs
    // if( 'example.com' !== $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] )

    add_filter( 'all_plugins', function( $plugins )
    {
        unset( $plugins['my-plugin/my-plugin.php'] ); 
        return $plugins;
    });
});
```