# Removing Dashboard Menu Items Through The Database

Tags: wp-admin, database, admin-menu

I'm dealing with a previous developer that's being difficult. He's removed the Plugin & Settings menus through the database (I'm assuming) as I can't find it anywhere in the functions.php file and can't access any plugin that might be used.

Can someone point me to a link on how this can be done in the database? Is it the users-meta table?

I'm really not sure what was done, and the developer stated:

> "he should easily know how to go into the cpanel with the username/password you already provided him, pull up the phpmyadmin interface and edit user(s) as necessary to provide any permissions."

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins and switched to a default theme (and verified that the problem persists)? I can't see how this is supposed to be due to a value in the database.

Comment: I'm really not sure what was done, and the developer stated: "he should easily know how to go into the cpanel with the username/password you already provided him, pull up the phpmyadmin interface and edit user(s) as necessary to provide any permissions."

It looks like he went in and changed something because now I can see what I need. However I'm still interested in knowing how to do this in the database if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

I know my way around WordPress' database pretty well and I would never call editing user permissions via PhpMyAdmin an easy thing to do. You are editing serialized strings-- very easy to get wrong, actually. So don't feel bad. There is something very wrong with that statement that "he should easily know how to ... edit user(s) as necessary to provide any permissions."

I can't promise this will work, but my administrator account on a relatively new install has this in the `$wpdb->postmeta` table...

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

... under the key `wp_capabilites`.

Find the `wp_capabilities` key associated with your (desired) admin user and past that into the `meta_value` column. Very quick and course testing suggests that should give your user all permissions. That is was able to elevate a "subscriber" to an admin that way. Be careful not to break that serializations. It has to be *exactly* like that to work. Change one character-- for example change one digit of 13 to make it 12-- and it will break and you will be looking at a "you don't have permissions" page.

However, that assumes that he "removed the Plugin & Settings menus" by editing permissions. I have my doubts. Had he done that it should be easy enough to put things back by way of the "User" form.

My guess would be that there is a `mu-plugin` file doing this (certainly what I'd do). Look in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` and see what you can see.

I'd also guess that if he's twitched the database like you suspect, he's twitched it in other ways as well.

Comment: oh, yes, mu-plugins is [prime suspect](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53866/12615). IMO, one has to be a SQL freak to do this kind of stuff directly in the database...

Answer (score 1):

*If* this was done by setting "permissions" via the database, the likely some [capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) were removed from your and possibly other [user roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Roles).

Given that the "Settings" and "Plugins" menus were inaccessible to you, it is a good guess that the capabilities [`manage_options`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#manage_options) and [`activate_plugins`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#activate_plugins) were not assigned to your user role.

Hence either you were given a non-admin user or the above caps had been removed from the admin role.

The roles themselves live in the `prefix_options` table in the option named `prefix_user_roles`.

The role a user is assigned to is indeed set in the `prefix_usermeta` table under the `meta_key` named `prefix_capabilities`.

*Neither should be edited directly in the DB though*.

The role a user is assigned to can be edited via the WP-native users admin menu.
WP does not natively provide an admin interface to edit roles and capabilities, but a bunch of decent plugins for just that do exist. Personally, I'd recommend checking out [Members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/).