# Change WordPress language based on user setting

Tags: localization

I want to change the language of my WordPress installation based on a choice the user can make in his profile (dropdown menu).

As I want to change frontend (prepared .mo files for the theme) and backend language I thought I could change the `$locale` variable and it would work out.

So I came up with the following code in my `functions.php` but that won´t do the job:

```
function change_lang() {
   get_currentuserinfo();
   $lang = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_lang');
   $locale = $lang[0];
   return $locale;
}
add_filter('locale', 'change_lang');
```

When I return the value of `$locale`, WP returns a simple `NULL`, nothing more. When I release the hook, the defined value from `WP_LANG()` is returned.

So, I am obviously wrong somewhere, but I can´t find where. Any hints?

Besides: [I read this for inspiration and code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53326/change-admin-language-based-on-user-in-single-site), but I don´t want to have it as a plugin if possible.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Fixed my code, but still no language change happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `$current_user` is a little wrong, you should include the `global $current_user` or assign it to a variable, or shorter and cleaner just `get_current_user_id()`:

```
add_filter('locale', 'change_lang');
function change_lang( $locale ) {

   if( $lang = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_lang', true) ) {
       return $lang;
   }

   return $locale;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my code. But still no language change at all. Any more ideas?

Comment: If you have implemented the user meta field "user_lang" and teh user has set the language, this code should work. Have you implemented that field?

Comment: I have, see this pastebin for my code: http://pastebin.com/v4pmV0xu

Also, showing the selected language in the frontend works, so updating etc. is doing fine.

Comment: @kaiser coded a [user language switcher](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/wcm_lang_switch), may he can say to us why this code is not working. I've been trying to find what can be wrong with no success.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out. I just had a look at the code, but I´m somehow just missing, where he sets the new locale.

Comment: He stores user language preference in `user_language` meta field, then use a similar code of this answer. See function definition in line 23 and filter declaration in line 103 in [this file](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/wcm_lang_switch/blob/master/wcm_lang_switch.class.php).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my plugin and nothing in here worked.

After days looking into it. I've realized that it is impossible to get the current user inside the filter 'locale'.
Not even calling the global `$user_locale`.

Apparently the hook 'locale' is triggered before init, or anythig else.

After all i found out that I was loading my plugin text domain before setting the locale. So, calling it right after `switch_to_locale()` fixed the problem.

This worked for me:

```
function set_user_locale(){

   switch_to_locale(get_user_locale());

   load_plugin_textdomain( 'plugin-texdomain', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' ); 

}
add_filter('init', 'set_user_locale');
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean this option ?

[image]

**If yes, then...**

```
$user_locale = get_user_locale();
function change_userlang_by_userlocale($locale){
    global $user_locale;
    return $user_locale ? $user_locale : $locale;
}
add_filter('locale','change_userlang_by_userlocale');
```