# How to bulk change user role to "No role for this site"

Tags: users, user-roles, user-access, bulk

If I edit an individual user, the role dropdown menu has the option "— No role for this site —" (`<option value="">— No role for this site —</option>`):

[image]

However this option doesn't exist on the main Users page :

[image]

So how can I go about changing the role of a group of users to "No role for this site" without having to change each one individually?

Comment: You could handle it by filter [`editable_roles`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/editable_roles), here the approach with different case by @kaiser http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53685/18731

Comment: @Jevuska - Funny, on the codex page you linked to there's an example at the bottom that seems like it's supposed to do what I'm after. Yet after adding that code to my functions.php file, the new option shows up, yet nothing changes one you click the change button.

Comment: Sure.. then you just need to figure it out in condtional statement and return them to array() only. Please, don't forget to update here if you have it.

Comment: If you're only wanting to do it once, and you're comfortable editing the database directly, you could possibly just do that too.